# How do I make one word in a string bold, when deploying the string to matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

I am trying to add text to a matplotlib axis in Python.

Here is the set up:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = 'This is a {}'.format('string')
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(x=0.5,y=0.5,s=s,ha='center',va='center',fontweight='normal')
```

That produces this outcome:

[image]

Specifically, what I want to do is make ONLY the word 'string' itself bold.  I have looked for ways to do this, but not been successful so far.

I have specifically set the s string up by deploying the word 'string' itself via the format method into the string, since I thought perhaps there is some way of attaching formatting parameters to the string then?

It seems in the ax.text options that I can only effect the weighting of the overall string by adjusting the fontweight parameter.

Is there an easy way to do this?  If not, perhaps a way of incorporating html syntax?

Thank you for any solution!  The most simple (I assume also therefore pythonic) is what I am really looking for!

Thanks!

---

Further edit in response to the possible solution using MathText.  If I wanted the string to be much longer and include line breaks, it is not clear how to also insert the line breaks without escaping the bold formatting.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = 'This is a' + r'$\bf{}$'.format('string, that is much longer than the last string.  I would like to insert a line break here.  Then continue with the sentence on a new line.')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.text(x=0.5,y=0.5,s=s,ha='center',va='center',fontsize=12,fontweight='normal')
```

produces:

[image]

However, if I insert a line break, it seems to escape the bold formatting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = 'This is a' + r'$\bf{}$'.format('string, that is much longer than the last string.  I would like to insert a line break here.\n  Then continue with the sentence on a new line.')
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax.text(x=0.5,y=0.5,s=s,ha='center',va='center',fontsize=12,fontweight='normal')
```

produces:

[image]

Note: It is also important that I be able to deploy the line breaks within the string itself, rather than adding multiple strings, since this is a process that I want to repeat over and over again as the output of other code i.e. not to have to fix by manually splitting up the string.

I realise that this may be slighty off topic now, but this is the culmination of the question!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the direction to the possible duplicate.  There is one extra demand that I did not outline in my original question that does not seem to work immediately given the explanation to the other question you reference.  I have updated my question to be more extensive.